# why would setting redirect in if and else condition wont work in php?

Tags: php, if-statement, http-headers, conditional-statements

Am baffled by a simple code even as experienced developer. Am trying to redirect a user depending on two condition.
I have a variable called $isMobile which is boolean.
Now below code cannot work if i add redirect but removing redirect header, it works

This does not work

```
if($isMobile){
    header('Location:http://localhost/myproject/mobile/login/');
    exit();
}
else{
    header('Location:http://localhost/myproject/pc/login/');
    exit();
}
//Error: too many redirects as if both conditions are true. Weird right?
```

This works

```
if($isMobile){
    echo 'redirect to mobile folder';
}
else{
    echo 'redirect to desktop folder';
}
```

What makes everything stop after adding both header redirects? I need to redirect users depending on their devices.
Am so stuck here guys.

Comment: Its not the PHP that is causing that error, its something in you `.htaccess` I would bet

Comment: Sure, you might be correct. On .htaccess am redirecting all requests to index.php

Comment: Is this file `index.php`

Comment: @RiggsFolly do you have any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: No, am running the above code in a file i included on index file

Comment: So basically YES it is part of `index.php` which redirects to `index.php` which redirects to `index.php` which redirects to `index.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238725/discussion-between-phi-lo-czar-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: maybe `if($isMobile && !$thisIsMobileApp){ ... } elseif(!$isMobile && $thisIsMobileApp){ ... }` ?